# get image from cam stream with python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv

trying to safe a simple image from a stream and save it but the apiPreference cant be found on line 7. already tried several things and read the [openCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html) information on the writer function but i cant find anything on the apiPreferences.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# Open the device at the ID 0

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
#fcc = cv2.VideoWriter_foucc(*"JPG")
out = cv2.VideoWriter("newImage.jpg", fourcc=0, fps=0)#line7

#Check whether user selected camera is opened successfully.

if not (cap.isOpened()):
    print("Could not open video device")

#To set the resolution

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

while(True):
    # Returns true and capture frame-by-frame and
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    snapShot = frame
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('preview', frame)
    
    out.write(snapShot)
    #Waits for a user input to quit the applicatio or save an image
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

just to get the fault:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File"home/pi/Dokuments/cameraStream.py", line 7, in <module>
 out = cv2.VideoWriter("newImage.jpg", fourcc=0, fps=0)
TypeError: Required argument 'apiPreference' (pos 2) not found
```

any idea on how to fix that would be great as im running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with the problems in your code.

- 1. ```py
     out = cv2.VideoWriter("newImage.jpg, fourcc=0, fps=0)#line7`
     ```

  ---

You initialize the `filename` variable to the image format ("newImage.jpg").

This is wrong. You need to initialize the `filename` by choosing one of the video-formats i.e. `.avi`, `.mp4` ..

You initialize `fourcc` to 0. I can't say it is wrong, but I can give a suggestion for a better initialization.

```py
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
```

As you can see above, I initialized my `fourcc` parameter for `mp4` video files.

You initialized `fps` to 0. Why? `fps` means frames-per-second meaning how many frames will you display in one second. My suggestion is set to 20. Of course, you can choose any other positive-integer.

- Now, what will be the dimension of your output video?

You have to set while declaring the `VideoWriter`. If you don't know and you would like to set the same dimension with the input video. You could do:

```py
ret, frame = cap.read()
(h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
out = cv2.VideoWriter("newVid.mp4", fourcc, 20, (w, h))
```

but, it seems you would like to set your dimensions to the (640, 480)

```py
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
out = cv2.VideoWriter("newVid.mp4", fourcc, 20, (640, 480))
```

One last thing is, specifying whether the output video is color or not.

```py
out = cv2.VideoWriter("newVid.mp4", fourcc, 20, (w, h), isColor=True)
```

- 2. ```py
     if not (cap.isOpened()):
         print("Could not open video device")
     ```

  ---

You are checking whether the video will be opened or not. But what happens if the video fails to open? According to the current logic it will continue. We should put an else statement.

```py
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Could not open video device")
else
    .
    .
```

- 3. ```py
     while(True):
         ret, frame = cap.read()
         snapShot = frame
     ```

Now what happens if `ret` is False? Application will throws an exception. Therefore you should do:

```py
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        snapShot = frame
```

Now why did you set `snapShot` variable to the frame?

You can directly write the input frames' copy. Like:

```py
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
        out.write(frame.copy())
```

One last thing, when you finish make sure to relase `VideoWriter` object too.

```py
out.release()
cap.release()
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
(h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
out = cv2.VideoWriter("newVid.mp4", fourcc, 20, (640, 480), isColor=True)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Could not open video device")
else:
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
            out.write(frame.copy())
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

out.release()
cap.release()
```

Comment: thx mate. will check your guide tomorrow morning completely.